# How to get the Handle that is executed in winexec or shellexecute?

Tags: delphi, shell, handle, shellexecute, hwnd

i use to create a custom function like winexec(...):Hwnd that will retun the handle of executed application.

i did use the findwindow() but having problem if it change window caption.

Comment: did you use SetWindowText(); in your custom function?SetWindowText();  will change caption back to what you want.
share your custom function maybe we'll be able to help you out
and sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: which window handle? main window? application handle? note that depending on the app you start, certain handles will never exist, or exist only (after and/or for) a while.

Comment: @Omair, if he could call SetWindowText to set the caption back to what he wanted, then that would mean he already had the window handle. Since he's *looking* for the window handle now, we can be confident that he doesn't already have it, and thus he can't call SetWindowText. Besides, it's a bad idea to change the caption of another program's windows.

Comment: @ rob: i was talking about the custom function he created,he said he used to create a custom fuction winexec(..):hwnd and used findwindow() function inside it(to get handle of the executed app) in a function like this i think it would be a good idea to keep the caption same(as it will change over time, suppose he is using internet explorer first the caption is say''welcome to yahoo'' then it changes to say ''yahoo search''), although i agree its a bad idea to use such a function and i am sorry for giving him that advice

Comment: you know guys, i had notice that not all application retuns the main window handle like having a splash screen. Too bad, what i did is use the ParamStr to sends the launcher HWND and then send the SubApss handle back to launcher.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no general way to get "the" window handle of an application because there's no guarantee that any program has one window handle. A program may have many top-level handles (i.e., Microsoft Word, one for each document), or it may have no windows at all. You might question what you really need the window handle for; there could be better ways of doing whatever it is you're trying to do that don't require any specific window handle.

`WinExec` (which has been deprecated for nearly 15 years, so you should seriously consider not using it anymore) and `ShellExecute` return absolutely no information about the programs they start, if indeed they start any program at all. (`ShellExecute` might use DDE to send a command to an already-running instance of the application.) And if they start an application, it might finish running before your program gets to run anymore.

You can use [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx) or [`ShellExecuteEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762154.aspx) instead. If they start a program, they will give you a process handle representing the program they started. You can use that to help you get additional information about the program, such as a list of its windows. Don't bother with `FindWindow`; the caption and window class aren't guaranteed to be unique; a program might use the same class name for many different windows, and multiple instances of a program would use the same class name without much way to select the one you really want.

`EnumWindows` is a function you can use to get a list of candidate window handles. You give it a function pointer, and it will call that function once for each top-level window on the desktop. You'll need a way of telling it which process you're interested in, and a way for it to return a list of results. The function only accepts one parameter, so the parameter will have to be a pointer to a structure that holds more information:

```
type
  PWindowSearch = ^TWindowSearch;
  TWindowSearch = record
    TargetProcessID: DWord;
    ResultList: TWndList;
  end;
```

`TWndList` is a type I made up to hold a list of `HWnd` values. If you have Delphi 2009 or later, you could use `TList<HWnd>`; for earlier versions, you could use a `TList` descendant or whatever else you choose.

`CreateProcess` will tell you the new process ID in the `dwProcessID` member of the `TProcessInformation` record it fills; `ShellExecuteEx` only returns a process handle, so use [`GetProcessID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683215.aspx) on that. The window-enumerating function needs a callback function matching this signature:

```
function SelectWindowByProcessID(Wnd: HWnd; Param: LParam): Bool; stdcall;
```

You can use `EnumWindows` to get a handle list like this:

```
function GetWindowListByProcessID(pid: DWord): TWndList;
var
  SearchRec: TWindowSearch;
begin
  Result := TWndList.Create;
  try
    SearchRec.TargetProcessID := pid;
    SearchRec.ResultList := Result;
    Win32Check(EnumWindows(SelectWindowByProcessID, LParam(@SearchRec)));
  except
    Result.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

You'll implement the callback function like this:

```
function SelectWindowByProcessID(Wnd: HWnd; Param: LParam): Bool; stdcall;
var
  SearchRec: PWindowSearch;
  WindowPid: DWord;
begin
  SearchRec := PWindowSearch(Param);
  Assert(Assigned(SearchRec));
  GetWindowThreadProcessID(Wnd, WindowPid);
  if WindowPid = SearchRec.TargetProcessID then
    SearchRec.ResultList.Add(Wnd);
  Result := True;
end;
```

Once you have the list, you can inspect other attributes of the window to determine which ones are really the ones you want. You might determine it by window title or class name, or perhaps by the other controls that are one that window.

When you're finished using the process handle, make sure you call `CloseHandle` on it so the OS can clean up the process's bookkeeping information.

Answer (score 2):

There is function named EnumWindows.
I think it will be useful to you.

Check the following links for more information

http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/l/aa080304a.htm

http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=327

Answer (score 0):

Try example 6 from this page (http://delphidabbler.com/tips/134) and just modify it a little bit. That's what I did.

if you want to split where you check and where you review your result you can do something like

```
var
  //...
  runNext : Boolean;
  //...

begin
{ startup code from other sample here }

// but instead of if
runNext := ShellExecuteEx(@SEInfo);

{ some more code here }

    // need delay before running next process
    // run loop until window with Handle is closed
if runNext then
    with SEInfo do
     repeat
      GetExitCodeProcess(SEInfo.hProcess, ExitCode);
      Sleep(20);
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      CheckSynchronize();
    until (ExitCode <> STILL_ACTIVE) or Application.Terminated;

{ next process code here }
end;
```

I realize some of you will drop hate mail on this for throwing in Sleep(), but I'd rather not lock windows up until that execute is finished when I'm processing a boatload of stuff and waiting.