# Delphi Open two files and re size whatever application they open in so they fit in the screen 50% 50%

Tags: delphi, winapi

If you have two random files e.g. .txt, .csv, .jpg, and you wanted to open two of them and make them take up the screen 50% 50%.
 
How would you find the window handle that was opened so that you can re size the right one?

I have edited below to be closer to the answer thanks to suggestions from David Heffernan and Rob Kennedy

The code below kind of works if everything goes right but i'm sure there are ways to improve the code.

---

Using ShellExecuteEx can return a process ID, you can get a window handle off the process ID by using EnumWindows checking against the process id. Then if everything works you can re size the form using MoveWindow

i have an example in the unit uFileStuff below

There are a few issues that i'm not sure can be resolved
Files can be opened in the same application e.g. notepad++.
ShellExecuteEx may not return a process id
EnumWindows may not find the window

Unit uFileStuff

```
unit uFileStuff;

interface
uses Winapi.Windows, System.SysUtils, Generics.Collections, shellapi, Winapi.Messages, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Forms;

type
  PWindowSearch = ^TWindowSearch;
  TWindowSearch = record
    TargetProcessID: DWord;
    ResultList: TList<HWnd>;
  end;

  TMyFile = class
  private
    sFileNameAndPath : String;
    MyProcessID : DWord;
    MyParentProcessID : Dword;
    Procedure OpenFile(sFile: String);
    procedure UpdateWindowListByProcessID;
  public
    WindowsLinkedToProcessID :  TList<HWnd>;
    function GetWindowInformation(Wnd: HWnd) : String;
    function GetAllWindowInformation : String;

    property ProcessID : Dword read MyProcessID;
    property ParentProcessID : Dword read MyParentProcessID;

    constructor Create(sFile : String);
    destructor Destroy; override;
end;

implementation

constructor TMyFile.Create(sFile: String);
begin
  MyProcessID       := 0;
  MyParentProcessID := 0;
  sFileNameAndPath := sFile;
  WindowsLinkedToProcessID := TList<HWnd>.Create;
  if (sFile <> '') and FileExists(sFile) then
    OpenFile(sFileNameAndPath);
end;

destructor TMyFile.Destroy;
begin
  WindowsLinkedToProcessID.Free;
  Inherited;
end;

function TMyFile.GetAllWindowInformation: String;
var i : Integer;
    sMessage : String;
begin
  result := '';
  for I := 0 to WindowsLinkedToProcessID.Count -1 do begin
    sMessage := sMessage + #13#10 + GetWindowInformation(WindowsLinkedToProcessID[i]);
  end;
  result := result + sMessage;
end;

function TMyFile.GetWindowInformation(Wnd: HWnd): String;
var Buffer: array[0..255] of char;
begin
  result := inttostr(Wnd);
  SendMessage(Wnd, WM_GETTEXT, 255, LongInt(@Buffer[0]));
  if Buffer <> '' then begin
    result := result + ', ' + Buffer;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyFile.OpenFile(sFile: String);
var i : Integer;
    SEInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
    ExitCode: DWORD;
    ExecuteFile, ParamString, StartInString, sMessage: string;
begin
  ExecuteFile:=sFile;
  FillChar(SEInfo, SizeOf(SEInfo), 0);
  SEInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
  with SEInfo do
  begin
    fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    Wnd := Application.Handle;
    lpFile := PChar(sFile);
    nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
  end;
  if ShellExecuteEx(@SEInfo) then
  begin
    if SEInfo.hProcess > 0 then begin
      Sleep(100);
      WaitForInputIdle(SEInfo.hProcess, 10000  );
      MyProcessID := GetProcessId( SEInfo.hProcess );
      UpdateWindowListByProcessID;
    end else begin
      ShowMessage('No Process ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError) );
    end;
  end else
    ShowMessage('Error starting "'+ sFile +'"' + #13#10 + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
end;

procedure TMyFile.UpdateWindowListByProcessID;
  function SelectWindowByProcessID(Wnd: HWnd; Param: LParam): Bool; stdcall;
  var
    pSearchRec: PWindowSearch;
    WindowPid: DWord;
  begin
    pSearchRec := PWindowSearch(Param);
    Assert(Assigned(pSearchRec));
    GetWindowThreadProcessID(Wnd, WindowPid);
    if (WindowPid = pSearchRec.TargetProcessID) and IsWindowVisible(Wnd) then
      pSearchRec.ResultList.Add(Wnd);
    Result := True;
  end;
var
  SearchRec: TWindowSearch;
begin
  if MyProcessID > 0 then begin
    SearchRec.TargetProcessID := MyProcessID;
    SearchRec.ResultList := WindowsLinkedToProcessID;
    EnumWindows(@SelectWindowByProcessID, LParam(@SearchRec));
  end;
end;

end.
```

Form Creating Files on create - has button to open them

```
unit fFileOpen;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TfrmFileOpen = class(TForm)
    btn1: TButton;
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    sApplicationPath : String;
    sFile1, sFile2 : String;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmFileOpen: TfrmFileOpen;

implementation
uses uFileStuff;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmFileOpen.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var File1 : TMyFile;
    File2 : TMyFile;
begin
  File1 := TMyFile.Create( sFile1 );
  try
    if sFile2 <> sFile1 then
      File2 := TMyFile.Create( sFile2 )
    else
      File2 := TMyFile.Create( '' );
    try
      if (File1.ProcessID > 0) and (File2.ProcessID > 0) then begin
        if (File1.ParentProcessID > 0) and (File2.ParentProcessID > 0) and (File1.ParentProcessID = File2.ParentProcessID) then begin
          showmessage('Both Files opened in same process');
        end else if (File1.WindowsLinkedToProcessID.Count > 0) and (File2.WindowsLinkedToProcessID.Count > 0) then begin
          if File1.WindowsLinkedToProcessID.Count > 1 then
            ShowMessage('Warning returned more than 1 window Moving the first window' + #13#10 + File1.GetAllWindowInformation);
          MoveWindow(File1.WindowsLinkedToProcessID[0], 0, 0, Trunc(Screen.WorkAreaWidth / 2), Screen.WorkAreaHeight, True);
          if File2.WindowsLinkedToProcessID.Count > 1 then
            ShowMessage('Warning returned more than 1 window Moving the first window' + #13#10 + File2.GetAllWindowInformation);
          MoveWindow(File2.WindowsLinkedToProcessID[0], Round(Screen.WorkAreaWidth / 2)+1, 0, Trunc(Screen.WorkAreaWidth / 2), Screen.WorkAreaHeight, True);
        end;
      end;
    finally
      File2.Free;
    end;
  finally
    File1.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmFileOpen.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var slTemp : TStringList;
    img    : TBitmap;
begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := true;
  sApplicationPath := ExtractFileDir(application.ExeName);
  sFile1 := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter( sApplicationPath ) + 'File1.txt';
  sFile2 := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter( sApplicationPath ) + 'File2.csv';
  {
  if not FileExists( sFile1 ) then begin
    img := TBitmap.Create;
    img.SetSize(300,300);
    img.SaveToFile( sFile1 );
    img.Free;
  end; }
  if not FileExists(sFile1) then begin
    slTemp := TStringList.Create;
    slTemp.Add('File1');
    slTemp.SaveToFile(sFile1);
    slTemp.Free;
  end;

  if not FileExists(sFile2) then begin
    slTemp := TStringList.Create;
    slTemp.Add('File2');
    slTemp.SaveToFile(sFile2);
    slTemp.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: This can never work. If you run that code on my machine, the files will open in two tabs of the same Notepad++ window. You will need to re-consider this. Also, as a general rule, never use `ShellExecute`. Use `ShellExecuteEx` in its place. `ShellExecute` does not report errors in a sane manner.

Comment: Good point - i've changed the files so that they are jpg and txt. Does ShellExecuteEx give you any access to the window handle

Comment: No it does not. It's plausible that even with jpg and txt, the files will be displayed in the same tabbed window. I think you need to think a bit harder about this. At least if you want it to be general.

Comment: No, but sometimes it gives you a process handle. I've written about [getting window handles from `ShellExecuteEx`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3046366/33732) before.