# Get Window Title if I only have the PID (Process ID)

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Using Delphi (in this case Delphi 7), how can I get Window Title from PID (process ID).

I am trying to capture the "Internet Explorer / Chrome" Window Title.

My code so far:

```
procedure GetAllBrowserTitle;
var
  hProcSnap    : THandle;
  pe32         : TProcessEntry32;
  P            : string;
  PID          : integer;
  ContinueLoop : BOOL;
begin

  try
    hProcSnap := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    if hProcSnap = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then exit;

    pe32.dwSize  := SizeOf(pe32);
    ContinueLoop := Process32First(hProcSnap, pe32);

    While (Integer(ContinueLoop) <> 0) do
    begin

      P := LowerCase(pe32.szExeFile);

      if (Pos('iexplore.exe', P) > 0) Or (Pos('chrome.exe', P) > 0) then
      begin
        PID   := pe32.th32ProcessID;
        // Get the Window Title
        // ???
      end;

      ContinueLoop := Process32Next(hProcSnap, pe32);
    end;

    CloseHandle(hProcSnap);

  except
  end;
end;
```

The part that I don't know is to get the Window Title. From my research, all examples requires Window Handle or using the EnumWindow callback which I am not quite understand.

Please if you can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Chrome has, potentially, many processes.  Some processes do own any windows. Some processes own many windows.  Chrome uses different processes for different browser tabs.  Whilst you might not understand `EnumWindow`, if it is the right function to solve your problem, you are going to need to learn how to use it. You need to stop what you are doing and understand the problem before you continue coding. There's no point trying to solve a problem that has not been correctly stated.

Comment: "...do NOT own any windows..." :-)

Comment: "EnumWindow callback which I am not quite understand" - then google for Delphi examples of using EnumWindows - there were many....

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know that chrome will have many processes, that doesn't matter. I was hoping there is a way to get the Window Title from PID. If it doesn't have any Windows, title would be empty or blank or whatever.

Comment: @Arioch'The Yes, I found many, but as I stated, I don't quite understand. Tried some of those examples, modified, and it doesn't work. It's ok if you also don't know. Thanks.

Comment: And what if the PID has many top level windows?  And what if those windows don't have titles because the titles are owned by child windows?  And what if the windows don't have captions held in the window text, but instead held elsewhere. I've already advised you that you don't understand the problem yet, but still you persist.  I won't say any more.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Good, thanks! :)

Comment: @ewlung "It's ok if you also don't know."  Oh dear.  Of course we know how to enumerate windows. We can do it in our sleep. But you don't know. And what's the point of us doing it for you. I'm only interested in helping people learn. If you don't want to learn, I've got nothing for you,

Comment: Wow. Snarky comments to two people who are trying to help you. Good luck with that, and with getting help from anyone else. A little advice: It's an extremely poor idea to get rude with the people you're asking to give you **free help** to solve **your problem**. It goes back to an old adage: *Don't bite the hand that feeds you.*

Comment: @KenWhite those are not just snarky comments. I guess you were to kindergarten and elementary school? You may recall then, that is how he urges us to please him to gain his approval :-)

Comment: See also [How to get the handle that is executed in WinExec or ShellExecute?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3046366/33732)

Comment: Looking at [pictures of Chrome on Windows](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=chrome+on+windows), it's not clear to me whether the windows even *have* titles. Likewise for various versions of Internet Explorer. This is why we suggest your problem isn't defined well enough. If you want the title of a particular *tab*, then you only need to say so, and you will be closer to expressing your real goal. If the tab title isn't what you want, then suggest something else.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have a PID, there are 2 ways you can discover the windows it has created.

1. Call [`EnumWindows()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497.aspx) to enumerate all top-level windows. The callback function you pass to it can use [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522.aspx) to check if each window belongs to the PID.
2. Use [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489.aspx), [`Thread32First()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686728.aspx), and [`Thread32Next()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686731.aspx) to enumerate all running threads, looking for ones that belong to the PID, calling [`EnumThreadWindows()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633495.aspx) on each matching thread.

Note that in both cases, you will be enumerating top-level windows only. If the target process creates child windows instead of top-level windows, especially with the intent of hosting those child windows in other windows of different processes, then you will have to use #1, but ignore the PID of the top-level windows and use [`EnumChildWindows()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494.aspx) to enumerate their child windows, using `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` on the child windows instead.